# How to test actors?

Tags: testing, akka

I have an actor , which on one of the messages run this method :

```
def addAuctions(actions:List[String]): Unit = {
var i = 0
for(auction <- actions) {
  val x = context.actorOf(Props(new Auction(auction, AUCTION_LIMIT_IN_SECONDS, self)), "auction" + i)
  x ! Auction.Init
  i= i+1
}
```

}

Then I have a following test :

```
"seller" in {
  val seller = system.actorOf(Props[Seller],"seller")
  seller ! Seller.NewAuctions(List("Laptop"))

  // HERE - HOW TO TEST IT ?

}
```

How Can I test if seller send message Auction.Init ?

Answer (score 1):

A good tutorial on testing actors is on the [Akka site](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html).

An straightforward way of achieving what you want is to extract the code creating the delegate actor to its own method, then override it with a test probe. So you can do something along the lines of the following.

```
class Foo extends Actor {
  // Suppose this is called after receiving a message called DoSomething
  def doSomething(): Unit = delegateActor ! SomeMsg
  def delegateActor: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props(...))
}
```

And in your test code,

```
class TestFoo(dActor: ActorRef) extends Foo {
  override def delegateActor = dActor
}

"test" in {
  val probe = TestProbe()
  val foo = TestActorRef(new TestFoo(probe))
  foo ! DoSomething
  probe.expectMsg(SomeMsg)
}
```